# i need some directions in comparing values from different sources using python

Tags: python, comparison

I need to compare values that i have by executing wmi commands(using python) and values from inside a db.. is it best to compare them without storing in separate files or is storing and then comparing is the only possible way?
can someone pls direct me in the right way.. also, where should i look for, for getting more knowledge regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, go for the simplest solution. In this case, compare them in memory.

If you want to be ultra-reliable (i.e. survive after crashes of your application / power outage) or cache values for long times (i.e. it's a requirement to continue working even when the database is down), you may consider files. Be warned though - anything but an extremely careful implementation (you should have lots of `try`..`except`..`finally`s and at least one call to `flock` and `fsync`, storing in files tends to be less reliable. So unless you're interested in consistency research and willing to put up a few weeks, go for a simple Python comparison.